# ICAL Recurrence RULE Generation (RRULE)

Tags: java, icalendar, ical4j

I need some help in understanding ICAL recurrence rule generation.

I have created a calendar with just one event in it. The event has a rule to re-occur on Every 2 Days for the Next 5 days.

The google calendar generates an ICS file with this.

```
...
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/New_York
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
...
```

This is the part which makes me confused.

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
```

---

**EDIT**

Full ICS File generated by google.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Public
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York
X-WR-CALDESC:dsdadsa
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/New_York
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140415
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20140416
DTSTAMP:20140319T053224Z
UID:n8gccbdmtb3gdgml543auul5ng@google.com
RECURRENCE-ID;VALUE=DATE:20140415
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20140319T053209Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20140319T053209Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:event details
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140413
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20140414
DTSTAMP:20140319T053224Z
UID:n8gccbdmtb3gdgml543auul5ng@google.com
RECURRENCE-ID;VALUE=DATE:20140413
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20140319T053209Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20140319T053209Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:event details
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140411
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20140412
DTSTAMP:20140319T053224Z
UID:n8gccbdmtb3gdgml543auul5ng@google.com
RECURRENCE-ID;VALUE=DATE:20140411
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20140319T053209Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20140319T053209Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:event details
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140409
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20140410
DTSTAMP:20140319T053224Z
UID:n8gccbdmtb3gdgml543auul5ng@google.com
RECURRENCE-ID;VALUE=DATE:20140409
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20140319T053209Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20140319T053209Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:event details
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140407
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20140408
DTSTAMP:20140319T053224Z
UID:n8gccbdmtb3gdgml543auul5ng@google.com
RECURRENCE-ID;VALUE=DATE:20140407
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20140319T053209Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20140319T053209Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:event details
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Instead of giving this

```
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5;INTERVAL=2
```

google created all the 5 events separately. Why.??

*Event start from April-7-2014*

*Is there any package for doing this in Java, saves me lot of time*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you have displayed is the timezone information (note the `BEGIN:VTIMEZONE` and `END:TIMEZONE`) and covers the start of daylight savings time for that timezone.  Specifically, daylight savings time starts on the second sunday of the third month of each year.

Try looking at the piece of code between `BEGIN:VEVENT` and `END:VEVENT` where you should see a `RRULE` for your event.

Generation of `RRULE`s is very dependent on your underlying data structures.  [Google has a project](https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/) which provides parsing and evaluation of `RRULE`s.

Comment: Thanks that's a good explanation. :) I thought the google is building things in a different way.!! 
Why is google building separate VEVENT instead of creating a Rule like `RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5;INTERVAL=2` ?

Comment: Please can you show the full calendar, including the `VEVENT`, so that I can explain?

Comment: Okay looking at that I can only guess that Google have hit issues with incompatibilities when users have attempted to import calendars with recurrence so they export each calendar entry individually.  Obviously this isn't possible if you have a RRULE which does not terminate, so you could try setting up some of those events and seeing how they export.

Comment: I have looked into the ics, they are creating individual events for the next 2 years, along  with that they are adding `RECURRENCE-ID;VALUE=DATE:20160308' and i still don't know what they meant by that.!

Comment: The `RECURRENCE-ID` is required because the events use the same `UID` and something is required to differentiate between them.  So it's either issues with other ICAL clients, or Google just being lazy/dumb when they generate ICS exports.  On that point, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: `RECURRENCE-ID;VALUE=DATE:20160310` is the value shown, i don't know what id is that because it already have a uid in it, which is common for all the event in same rule. And the most mysterious thing is they haven't specified the rule anywhere else.

Comment: The combination of `UID` and `RECURRENCE-ID` must be unique for every `VEVENT` in the calendar.  Usually there will be a `VEVENT` with the `RRULE` and no `RECURRENCE-ID` for the primary event, and then there will be separate `VEVENT`s with `RECURRENCE-ID` for any events which deviate from the primary (change of date/time/location/summary/whatever).  Google's way of doing it is technically valid, but could be considered to be outside of the spirit of how recurring events should be encoded.  Maybe they didn't manage to write a decent `RRULE` generator?

Comment: now that helps, now my confusions regarding why google ics file works is almost solved. Thanks for the help :)